# How to use reflection to set nested struct field values

Tags: go, struct, nested

I'm using Go to create a nested struct and populate it. I have a custom field in the struct that I need to set myself, but it's a type used in a field of the outer struct. For example:

```
type Case struct {
   CaseID            string         `json:"caseID"`
   CaseStatus        string         `json:"caseStatus"`
   Kit_Details       []Kit_Details  `json:"kit_Details"`
}

type Kit_Details struct {
    KitID          string    `json:"kitID"`
    KitStatus      string    `json:"kitStatus"`
}
```

I have created a nested struct. I want to update `KitStatus` fields using Case struct in my program.Means if I access Case struct from that how can i move to `Kit_Details` struct and update the field of a structure.
Can somebody help me how to loop through the fields of Case struct using `FieldByName("KitStatus")` and using `SetString("New value")` to update the value of that field.

Comment: If the type is already known, why do you need reflection?

Comment: The `Kit_Details` field is a slice, you can use https://golang.org/pkg/reflect/#Value.Len and https://golang.org/pkg/reflect/#Value.Index to loop over the elements of the slice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use like this:

```golang
v := reflect.ValueOf(test)
fmt.Println("Value of test before update", v)
v.FieldByName("Kit_Details").Index(0).FieldByName("KitStatus").SetString("abcdsdf")
```

You can use a loop to traverse all the elements and update them using `Index()`.

[Go play ground link](https://play.golang.org/p/WSsNfBC8EMM)

Comment: if I want to store all the updated value in existing structure then what would be the way to do it. I am posting the way i am trying

Comment: Please post your tried way in go playground @Suva. And also please accept my answer and give an upvote it is helpful for you. Thank you.

Comment: @ Fahim,Please find go playground link  https://play.golang.org/p/7EKOtsyzCBJ